# How to access the full path of the active notebook from within "kernel"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I access the file name from within the kernel?

The "kernel" is a name used from an example extension provided by vscode an instance of the kernel class is passed into `context.subscriptions.push`.

here's what I tried:

```
vscode.window.showInformationMessage(vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders && vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.path || '1')
vscode.window.showInformationMessage(vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.uri.path || "2")
vscode.window.showInformationMessage(vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.fileName || "3")
```

this prints

```
/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/vscode-nodebook
2
3
```

How can I access the full path of the notebook file?

Answer (score 0):

This will log the name of the file when it's selected (tab is opened).

```
this._controller.onDidChangeSelectedNotebooks(e => {
  if (e.selected === false) return;
  
  vscode.window.showInformationMessage(e.notebook.uri.path)
})
```